# Can't find the jar for ImportLinkedInProfile

Tags: java, linkedin-api

I am trying to use LinkedIn in a simple JSP-Servlet based application. In the sample code which I have there is a class called ImportLinkedInProfile. I am finding it difficult to get the jar for this. Any ideas which jar has this? I tried findjar.com but its not listing this class.

```
com.cs.liveebiz.server.common.ui.ImportLinkedInProfile;
```

Code snippet where this is used -

```
ImportLinkedInProfile importProfile = new ImportLinkedInProfile();
importProfile.processImportedResult(profile);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reference I can find to this class is via a rather useless [blog posting](http://javacompleteexamples.blogspot.co.uk/2010_03_01_archive.html).

Given that his example includes the same package declaration as the one you are trying to import (package com.cs.liveebiz.server.linkedinapi) I'd suggest that this is a custom wrapper developed by him.

Regardless, the actual meat of the code is from the [linkedin-j](http://code.google.com/p/linkedin-j/) project. I've not used that library but it appears to support fetching of a [Person](http://code.google.com/p/linkedin-j/wiki/GettingStarted#Profile_API_Example) from LinkedIn. I imagine the class you are wanting to use from JAR is a simple wrapper which maps from a linkedin-j Person object to some other bean suitable for presentation on a webpage.

In fact, on further inspection of the code on that blog posting, it appears that this class isn't used at all (it's difficult to tell without the source code and the name is fairly obtuse).

Comment: Thanks Steve N. I will try to modify the code without this class.